# Int variable won't overwrite in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently writing some scripts for my Unity project. However, I have run into some issues regarding overwriting variables. I am utterly confused, as based on my understanding there should not be any issue.

As you can see in the code below the the variable `tempChernoff` is originally initialized globally with the value 0. In the method `selectChernoff()`this value is meant to be overwritten depending on which of two buttons is being clicked. This works fine and the variable gets overwritten. However, once the method `selectCountry()`is run, `tempChernoff` is still 0 and it's like the new initialization never happened.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using CountryClass;
using System;
using System.IO;
using CsvHelper;
using System.Globalization;
using TMPro;

public class MapButtons : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int tempChernoff = 0;
    private string chernoffName;

    private GameObject currentButton;
    private GameObject chernoffAvatar;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //initialize current Button
        currentButton = this.gameObject;
        // read data from csv file
        var reader = new StreamReader("Assets/Resources/Country_dataset.csv");
        var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var data = csv.GetRecords<Country>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    
    //selects select Avatar to be changed by changing int value
    public void selectChernoff()
    {
        switch (currentButton.name)
        {
            case "Chernoff1":
                tempChernoff = 1;
                this.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(102, 255, 51);
                Debug.Log(tempChernoff);   // prints 1 to console
                break;
            case "Chernoff2":
                tempChernoff = 2;
                this.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(102, 255, 51);
                Debug.Log(tempChernoff);    //prints 2 to console
                break;
        }
    }

    // changes country of the avatr that was previously selected
    public void selectCountry()
    { 
       
        Debug.Log(tempChernoff);   // prints 0 to console?
        switch (tempChernoff)
        {
            case 1:
                // change button sprite back to original color
                chernoffAvatar = GameObject.Find("Chernoff1");
                chernoffAvatar.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(130, 130, 130);
                // find the actual avatar object
                chernoffAvatar = GameObject.Find("ChernoffAvatar1");
                break;
            case 2:
                // change button sprite back to original color
                chernoffAvatar = GameObject.Find("Chernoff2");
                chernoffAvatar.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(130, 130, 130);
                // find the actual avatar object
                chernoffAvatar = GameObject.Find("ChernoffAvatar2");
                break;
            case 0:
                Debug.Log("No ChernoffAvatar Selected");
                break;
        }

        if(tempChernoff != 0)
        {
            var currentCountry = chernoffAvatar.transform.Find("Country Text").GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text;
            Debug.Log(currentCountry);
            Debug.Log(currentButton.name);
        }


    }
}
```

Obviously this does not throw an error compilation wise (It just logs the "No Chernoff avatar selected" message to console), but rather an error in my logic or understanding of C#.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that selectChernoff() and selectCountry() are called for the same instance of  MapButtons? it looks like the methods are called on different instances.

Comment: Are you using two different instances of `MapButtons`?

Comment: I would start by making `tempChernoff ` private.

Comment: All instance fields are initialzed (to default) when the instance is created, which is in `Start` and [`Awake`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html#:~:text=Awake%20is%20called%20when%20an,Instantiate%20is%20initialized.). "Awake is called either when an active GameObject that contains the script is initialized when a Scene loads, or when a previously inactive GameObject is set to active, or after a GameObject created with Object. Instantiate is initialized"

Comment: This is why it is good to add context to your log messages like `Debug.Log(someText, this);`.Then you can click on the log message and see from where it came.